# Weird issue with catching trivial boost exception

Tags: c++, boost, exception

I have an issue with the following straightforward code:

```
    try
    {
        boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>("invalid string");
    }
    catch(::boost::bad_lexical_cast &)
    {
        //It's not catched!!!
        return;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e){
        std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(e) << std::endl;

        ::boost::bad_lexical_cast s;
        std::string ss = typeid(s).name();
        std::cout << "'" << s.what()<<"': '"<< ss <<"'";

        std::string ee = typeid(e).name();
        std::cout << "'" << e.what()<<"': '"<< ee <<"'";
    }
```

The `boost::bad_lexical_cast` exception thrown by `lexical_cast` is somehow *different* than the one I try to catch, so the first catch is simply ignored.
One exception is of type:

(mangled)
`N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_16bad_lexical_castEEEEE`

that is a:

```
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >
```

while the other one simply `boost::bad_lexical_exception`.

My question is: how can I better debug such a situation? Why does it happen only locally while n another environment the issue doesn't appear? And how can I prevent these weird behaviours?

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The weird type you see is a `boost::exception_detail::clone_impl< boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector< boost::bad_lexical_cast>>`. It's a wrapper around (and derived from) `bad_lexical_cast` provided by Boost.Exception, which provides support for `boost::exception_ptr` and the error info facilities. It should be caught just fine by the first catch.

When it isn't, that's usually an effect of conflicting RTTI information in different dynamic libraries. It's the only thing I can think of to explain the behavior of your test case.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about RTTI conflicts too, even if I import only one boost library version there must be some duplication/double import. Still, I have not any idea on how I can track down this issue... I tried lib dependencies but I don't see anything wrong with them ....